# Is is possible to pipe kernel messages from a specific process to a file

Tags: linux, logging, linux-kernel, pipe

Since it's a Linux question, I'll note I'm using OpenSUSE 12.1

I'm running a kernel module, basically it's a CAN bus simulator, and it prints messages via `printk()` whenever there is activity on the 'bus'.

I'm tracing the messages right now with `sudo cat /proc/kmsg`, but when I start putting other "devices" on the "bus" the kmsg traffic is greatly incressed and it's hard to find my messages.

Is there anyway to pipe the "printk" messages from one specific process to a file?

**EDIT**
I see now there are possibilties if I add specific tags to my debug messages, are there any other ways?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes, you can. All kernel messages can hold syslog-ng daemon. For this daemon you can write custom rules and put all messages from your module to specific file. Take first look at /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf

**update**

By default, all kernel print and printk functions put messages to kernel ring buffer. Userspace programs can access to this ring buffer thought /proc/kmsg file.

Syslog-ng will read data from /proc/kmsg, then, via filter (filter is just special pattern) grep output and put data in different output (in this example it will be just text files). If in output buffer we will find output from kernel module "hello", syslog-ng will put messages to /var/log/hello, all other messages will go to /var/log/messages

Module source

```
#include <linux/module.h>       
#include <linux/kernel.h>       

#define MODNAME "[hello]"

int init_module(void)
{
        printk(KERN_WARNING MODNAME "Hello world 1.\n");    
        return 1;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye world 1.\n");
}
```

After insmod

> insmod hello-1.ko

in /var/log/messages you can find:

> Sep 20 17:46:20 ns1 kernel: [96643.968650] [hello]Hello world 1.

ok, lets configure syslog-ng to catch grep log message (by using pattern [hello])

$cat /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf

```
@version: 3.2
# $Header: /var/cvsroot/gentoo-x86/app-admin/syslog-ng/files/syslog-ng.conf.gentoo.3.2,v 1.1 2011/01/18 17:44:14 mr_bones_ Exp $
#
# Syslog-ng default configuration file for Gentoo Linux

options {
        chain_hostnames(no);    
        stats_freq(43200);
        mark_freq(3600);
};

source src {
    unix-stream("/dev/log" max-connections(256));
    internal();
    file("/proc/kmsg");
};

destination messages { file("/var/log/messages"); };
# output file for ower module
destination hello_messages { file("/var/log/hello"); };   

# grep patterns for ower module
filter f_hello { match("hello" value("MESSAGE")); };
filter f_kernel { facility(kern); };

log { source(src); destination(messages); };
log { source(src); destination(console_all); };

# target for logging    
log { source(src); filter(f_hello); filter(f_kernel); destination(hello_messages); };
```

Comment: OK, I guess this wasn't in my Distro so I downloaded it and am taking a look. Any example on the syntax? I get some of it... but I don't see how the filter maps to the process that it's filtering.

Comment: +1 excellent answer and example. I'll leave the question open for a day in case there's another answer that doesn't involve me tagging all my prints, but I think this will be accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to achieve this: using any recent kernel's built-in "ftrace" support.

a) for very high volume printk traffic, printk might cause system bottlenecks or even a crash- you should then switch to using trace_printk(); it's overhead is almost insignificant (esp compared to printk)
b) ftrace has the ability to filter the ftrace ring buffer for a specific process.

Pl read up details here (within any recent kernel source tree):
*Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt*

Addn resources:
"Debugging the kernel using Ftrace - part 1"
http://lwn.net/Articles/365835/ 
(See part 2 as well).