# IS it possible to send Kernel Messages from syslog-ng to a characther device node

Tags: logging, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, syslog, syslog-ng

I am running a USB Kernel module and it prints messages via printk().
I am using syslog-ng(3.4.5) ,based on the method shown in this link
---> http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/12500273/is-is-possible-to-pipe-kernel-messages-from-a-specific-process-to-a-file
iam filtering out messages based on tags and sending them to an emlog 0.52 based characther device file (/tmp/hello).
At the same time i did a simple read (isssued cat /tmp/hello) on the device file.
Problem is i am unable to get any messages into /tmp/hello ,
Is it possible to redirect messages from syslog-ng to a characther device file?? or Is there any easy way to accomplish this?

I was able to get messages by using command line "klogd" ,but i cannot filter out taged messages.

Comment: Can you pipe klogd through grep?  It's unclear what role you want to have the character device file play - do you just want to write them to a text file?  That's not a "device file" (ie device node created with mknod) which is a type of kernel interface, but simply a plain regular file.

Comment: I haven't implemented klogd through grep!can you tell me what command should i issue to use klogd through grep??

sorry! yes! its a device node, emlog creates a separate circular buffer ,we have to create a device node with mknod with same major number as of emlogs in /dev and a minor number for buffer size.

@http://www.circlemud.org/jelson/software/emlog/

I was able to send klogd messages to this node! All i need is to filter those messages based on printk Tags(shown in my above comment) and send them to emlog's separate device node!

Thanks for replying!